# clone SD card on debian/ubuntu with system on

Tags: debian, clone, sd-card

I have 2 SD(same size) cards with linux systems on both of them. But only one is working. I want to clone this card to the other one to make exact copies.

When i insert them both to my debian i see:

```
GOOD CARD
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb2

BAD CARD
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc2
```

I've tried `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4M` but it didn't work. Now the bad card won't boot at all. Is there a way to reformat the card and clone it to make exact copy by script? I thought that dd will make this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with some error handling enabled:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror,sync
```

- notrunc or 'do not truncate' maintains data integrity by instructing dd not to truncate any data.
- noerror instructs dd to continue operation, ignoring all read errors. Default behavior for dd is to halt at any error.
- sync writes zeroes for read errors, so data offsets stay in sync.